# How to set snap to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have set my snap element of the draggable like so:

```
$('#id_num_'+id_num).draggable({snap:'.time_column', snapMode:'inner'})
```

How do I set up my draggable element to snap to two different elements or classes...like so:

```
$('#id_num_'+id_num).draggable({snap:'.time_column', '.**other class**', snapMode:'inner'})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
$('#id_num_'+id_num).draggable({snap:'.time_column,.other_class', snapMode:'inner'})
```

Comment: ugh, I tried writing it so many ways EXCEPT that. haha, thanks